# Running Gradle Build Script from Java Desktop Application for Android App

Tags: java, android, javafx, build.gradle

I'm trying to automate building of an Android app through a Java Desktop app by pressing a **build** button - as I need to change some manifest values, and string values. All that is done, but I need to perform a "gradle assembleRelease -pMyProjectPath," but I keep running into issues. Here are the combinations I've tried:

**Test 1**

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("call", "gradle", "assemble ", "-p" , projectPath);
```

**Output for Test 1:**

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "call": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I tried the "call" since from what I understand, gradle isn't an executable (it was a shot in the dark)

**Test 2**

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( "C:\\developer\\tools\\gradle-2.3\\bin\\gradle", "assemble ", "-p"+projectPath);
```

**Output for Test 2**

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\developer\tools\gradle-2.3\bin\gradle": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

gradle is in my environment path.

**Test 3**

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "gradle", "assemble ", "-p" + projectPath);
```

**Output for Test 3:**
-- None. There is no output. Don't know if it's running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One the big issues is that I didn't include the "/C" in the ProcessBuilder paramter.

And here's my working version for compiling with gradle from UI:

```
  private void startGradleExecutorService() {
    statusLabel.setText("Building...");
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.submit(() -> {

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", projectPath + "/gradlew assembleRelease -p" + projectPath, "--info");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            Process p = builder.start();
            BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            System.out.println("outputString:: " + stdout.readLine());

            while ((outputString = stdout.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("outputString:: " + outputString);
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    //if you change the UI, do it here !

                    statusLabel.setText(outputString);

                });
                if (outputString.contains("BUILD")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            p.getInputStream().close();
            p.getOutputStream().close();
            p.getErrorStream().close();
            p.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```